# Displaying latest Tweets on mywebsite .. User name not coming

Tags: twitter, tweets

Hi i have integrated twitter api to display recent tweets on my website .

I can able to get the recent tweets but tweets does't contains user name(user who has tweeted on my wall)

below is the code i have used

```
<div id="twitter_update_list" style="height:300px;width:300px; overflow:auto; overflow-x:hidden">
```

javascipt

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=ABMMyuniverse&include_rts=true&count=4&callback=twitterCallback2"></script>
```

output :

Aditya Birla Money MyUniverse is now a proud winner of Finnoviti-2012, an award for inspiring innovations in the financial services sector 122 days ago

Team MyUniverse wishes everyone a very # Happy Diwali, May the lights spread joy, peace and prosperity in your life! http://t.co/xbCUSRrT 133 days ago

only tweets text i'm getting .. there is no user details ..How can i get that ??

someone please help me .. thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have integrated . I hope this will help some one :)

```
 <script language="javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {
       var username = 'YourTwitterName';
       $.getScript('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=' + username + '&callback=twitterCallback2&count=4');
     });

     function twitterCallback2(twitters)
     {
     var statusHTML = [];
     for (var i=0; i<twitters.length; i++){
     var username = twitters[i].user.screen_name;
     var profileimage = twitters[i].user.profile_image_url;
     var status = twitters[i].text.replace(/((https?|s?ftp|ssh)\:\/\/[^"\s\<\>]*[^.,;'">\:\s\<\>\)\]\!])/g, function(url) {
     return '<a href="'+url+'">'+url+'</a>';
      }).replace(/\B@([_a-z0-9]+)/ig, function(reply) {
      return  reply.charAt(0)+'<a href="http://twitter.com/'+reply.substring(1)+'">'+reply.substring(1)+'</a>'; });

      statusHTML.push('<table style="border-top:1px dotted #000"><tr><td><a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/' + username + '">' + username + ':</a><br/>' + status + ' <br/><small style="color:#737373">' + relative_time(twitters[i].created_at) + '</small></td></tr></table>');
    }

      $('.loading').fadeOut(800, function() {
      $('#userlatest_tweet').append($(statusHTML.join('')).hide().fadeIn(750));                             
      }); 
      }      
      function relative_time(time_value) {
      var values = time_value.split(" ");
      time_value = values[1] + " " + values[2] + ", " + values[5] + " " + values[3];
      var parsed_date = Date.parse(time_value);
      var relative_to = (arguments.length > 1) ? arguments[1] : new Date();
      var delta = parseInt((relative_to.getTime() - parsed_date) / 1000);
      delta = delta + (relative_to.getTimezoneOffset() * 60);
      if (delta < 60) {
      return 'less than a minute ago';
      }
      else if (delta < 120) {
      return 'about a minute ago';
      }
      else if (delta < (60*60)) {
      return (parseInt(delta / 60)).toString() + ' minutes ago';
      }
      else if(delta < (120*60)) {
      return 'about an hour ago';
      } else if(delta < (24*60*60)) {
      return 'about ' + (parseInt(delta / 3600)).toString() + ' hours ago';
      } else if(delta < (48*60*60)) {
      return '1 day ago';
      else {
      return (parseInt(delta / 86400)).toString() + ' days ago';
     }
   } 
  }


</script>
<div id="userlatest_tweet" style="height: 300px; overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden">
                <div class="loading">
                </div>
 </div>
```

you can add image also by modifying table inside **statusHTML.push** function ....!!!!

If it is working fine .. then **make this as answer** which will be helpful for others !!!